# Powershell Error - Null/Empty Argument

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, database-connection

I have a small powershell script that is meant to get column ServerName from a remote SQL database called, Hal0Test > from table, ServerList. However, I can not figure out this Powershell Error.

**Newest Code:**

```
Write-Output " `n Start of Hal0 `n";

$connectionString = "Server=QAUTILITYDB01;Database=Hal0Test;Integrated Security=True;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()

$ServerArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$query = "SELECT ServerName FROM ServerList"
$command.CommandText = $query
$ServerNames = $command.ExecuteReader()

$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$table.Load($ServerNames)

$ServerArray = $table | select -Expand ServerName

$ServerArray | ForEach-Object {
    # $Server returns each server name
    $os    = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $_
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Computer $_ |
             Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} |
             ForEach-Object {
                 '{0} {1:D} MB Free/{2:D} MB Used' -f $_.DeviceID,
                     [int]($_.FreeSpace/1MB), [int]($_.Size/1MB)
             }

    New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
      'FQDN'            = $_
      'ServerName'      = $os.PSComputerName
      'OperatingSystem' = $os.Caption
      'Disks'           = $disks -join ' | '
    }
    $command.CommandText = "UPDATE ServerList SET FQDN = '$_', OS = '$os.Caption' WHERE ServerName = '$os.PSComputerName';"
    $result = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()  
} | Export-Csv 'C:\Users\king\Desktop\HalO\output.csv' -Delimiter '|' -NoType
Write-Output "`n End of Hal0";
```

**SQL Table:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You changed my `ForEach-Object` loop to a `foreach` loop. If you want to use the latter you need to change the current object variable `$_` to your loop variable `$Server`:

```
foreach ($Server in $ServerArray) {
  $os    = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $Server
  $disks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Computer $Server | ...

  ...
}
```

otherwise you need to change the loop back to a `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
$ServerArray | ForEach-Object {
  $os    = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $_
  $disks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Computer $_ | ...

  ...
}
```

Also, there's no pipe between `}` and `Export-Csv`:

```
    $result = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()  
} Export-Csv 'C:\Users\mdaraghmeh\Desktop\HalO\output.csv' -Delimiter '|' -NoType
 ^
here
```

And even if there were would the `foreach` loop still be unable to feed its output into the pipeline. If you want to use `foreach` with a pipeline you must assign the output to a variable:

```psh
$output = foreach ($Server in $ServerArray) { ... }
$output | Export-Csv ...
```

or run it in an expression:

```psh
(foreach ($Server in $ServerArray) { ... }) | Export-Csv ...
```

For direct pipeline processing you need a `ForEach-Object` loop:

```psh
$ServerArray | ForEach-Object { ... } | Export-Csv ...
```

Comment: For the direct pipeline I do not understand, I have editted my code to reflect your advice.

Comment: So add a "|" between } <HERE> Export-Csv and for the direct pipeline what goes into the loop {...}? What I am misssing in my new code?

Comment: The ellipsis (`...`) is just a placeholder for the code from the body of your loop. Why do you think you need to change anything there?

Comment: I do not know what to make the loop do lol? Honestly I am very confused and would love the help. For this is first project like this and I would like to do more to get the hang of Powershell/SQL

Comment: What's wrong with leaving the code inside the loop as it is? Does something not work as expected? Do you get an error?

Comment: When I run the code above it produces that error. I am not sure I followed your advice correctly. I added in ForEach-Object loop and the " | " but my program is still not producing the csv file nor populating the database @Ansgar Wiechers

Comment: @TheAce The reader is closed after you loaded the data into your data table. Replace the `while` loop with `$ServerArray = $table | select -Expand ServerName`.

Comment: That solved the bad .csv file but my table in SQL is not updating with anything or getting new information from the powershell script. Please see new code/new table

Comment: @TheAce Your table isn't updated because your `WHERE` clause never matches an existing entry. Please go back to the answer where you got that and re-read my comment there to understand what is wrong with it. This is my final response to this question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `[datatable]` to store the result of your select:

```
$connectionString = "Server=QAUTILITYDB01;Database=Hal0Test;Integrated Security=True;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()

$ServerArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$query = "SELECT ServerName FROM ServerList"
$command.CommandText = $query
$ServerNames = $command.ExecuteReader()

$table = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"
$table.Load($ServerNames)
```

Now `$table` has your servers name list.

Comment: Thank you @CB. but now I am gettig a weird error as well as an InputObject command in the console.

Comment: @TheAce the result of your select is in `$table`. You don't need any more `$servernames.read()` ... you follow me? Need to change `foreach($Server in $ServerArray)` in `foreach($Server in $table)` and go

Comment: would you mind editting your answer with the full code for I am not completetly getting what you are saying. Sorry about that